# How to share a wireless internet connection wirelessly?

Tags: networking, wireless, internet

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to share a wireless internet connection via wireless hot spot.

All of the solutions I can find say that I need an Ethernet cable plugged in. I can set this up in Windows without a cable so I know my 2021 HP x360 Envy is capable.

I've been searching for two days and tried all of the old answers and haven't found any new solutions for this problem. I want to use the laptop as a hot spot while it is connected to wireless internet. I really want to get away from Windows completely and this is only issue stopping me. I'm a newbie to Ubuntu but I learn quick.

Comment: Most wireless chipsets cannot be both network client and network master simultaneously. If yours is the rare one with that hardware capability, you also need the Linux driver to support such use, which is doubtful.

Comment: You may need a hardwire connection to setup the wireless hotspot. May I know why you need to connect the other device through the hotspot? It may be easier to have the other device connect to the wireless network and let the router handle it.

Comment: In the community where I live wireless internet is free so there is no wired connection. But we're only allowed to have two devices on it. So creating a hotspot on the computer can have eight devices connected at least in Windows 10 and 11. Seems Linux would have the same feature out of the box. I know Windows does it by creating a virtual connection.

Comment: This looks promising https://github.com/lakinduakash/linux-wifi-hotspot. I'll give it a shot when I have a free day to reformat my computer twice if it doesn't work.

Comment: Wonder why this isn't already built into Linux though?

Comment: Don't add "Solved" to a question title. If you have a solution, kindly post an answer in the answer section. However, please don't post a link-only answer. You should use links for reference or citation. Future visitors could benefit from a clearly written solution.